# Scrolling the page causes issues to buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button, scroll

I just finished a website, everything was working fine (what I thought)
Until I discover a huge BUG that couldn't fix:

I have a navigation BAR (png file) and added on it buttons (simple DIVs elements), When the page is openned 1st, all is fine, but if you scroll the page a bit, the buttons aren't working as they should.

Please check this link: (scroll the page a bit down and you'll notice that button aren't interacting anymore)

http://www.genius-solutions.net/GSIS/index.html

But if you move the cursor a bit above the buttons, you'll find them:

(HTML - JavaScript)

here the CSS part:

```
#btn {position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:4;}
#btn1 {position:absolute;left:80px;top:280px;width:140px;height:35px;background:#DDE6E3;opacity:0.0;cursor:pointer;}
#btn2 {position:absolute;left:230px;top:280px;width:140px;height:35px;background:#DDE6E3;opacity:0.0;cursor:pointer;}
#btn3 {position:absolute;left:380px;top:280px;width:140px;height:35px;background:#DDE6E3;opacity:0;cursor:pointer;}
#btn4 {position:absolute;left:530px;top:280px;width:140px;height:35px;background:#DDE6E3;opacity:0;cursor:pointer;}
#btn5 {position:absolute;left:680px;top:280px;width:140px;height:35px;background:#DDE6E3;opacity:0;cursor:pointer;}
#btn6 {position:absolute;left:830px;top:280px;width:140px;height:35px;background:#DDE6E3;opacity:0;cursor:pointer;}

#html, body {
    background:#002a4c;
    overflow:scroll;
    width:1024px;
    height:768px;
    margin: 20px auto; /* center */ padding: 20px;

}
```

and here the HTML part:

```
    <body >
    <div id = 'applet' home='579' services='1437' solutions='1192' partners='100' aboutus='654' contacts='216'>

       <div id='applet_t'>

            <div id='btn'>
                <div id='btn1'></div>
                <div id='btn2'></div>
                <div id='btn3'></div>
                <div id='btn4'></div>
                <div id='btn5'></div>
                <div id='btn6'></div>
            </div>

    </div>
        <div id='inf'></div>


    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please provide a better explanation or a jsFiddle to use

Comment: Whats your browser? Same issue when using different browsers? What's your resolution? It doesn't look broken with crome and full HD. Get firebug and do a little try and error.

Comment: yes , same issue with all browsers - IE - Chrome - Safari - Firefox -

Comment: should i paste the entire codes ? (long scripts)

Comment: This problem isn't from buttons positioning , since i changed the buttons color &opacity , and they'r always in the same place after scrolling , even the cursors behavior is interacting well ... but the problem is only on the buttons functions (on "mouseenter" - "mouseleave" - "mousedown") that are interacting with wrong place... 

am using jquery 1.8.2.

Any help gys ? anyway to use instead of .on('mouseenter',function(){}) in javascript???

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lies in IMO very improper use of `absolute` positioning of your elements. As soon as you scroll the page the location of the actual "hit" placeholder moves with the page but not your background.

Test case: try to move your page up a little bit and you will be able to "click" above the actual buttons.

Unless you have a good reason for absolutely positioned element use `static` == default positioning for most of your elements.

Comment: What do you mean by move your page ? (scroll) or move it in the HTML script ?
And please what you suggest to me so i can fixe this issues?

Comment: scroll in browser. To fix I mean to use semantic HTML, such as anchors for links (not divs) etc.

Comment: This problem isn't from buttons positioning , since i changed the buttons color &opacity , and they'r always in the same place after scrolling , even the cursors behavior is interacting well ... but the problem is only on the buttons functions (on "mouseenter" - "mouseleave" - "mousedown") that are interacting with wrong place... 

am using jquery 1.8.2.

Any help gys ? anyway to use instead of .on('mouseenter',function(){}) in javascript???

Comment: you have not fixed them.  `Absolute` positioning is different from `fixed` positioning.  `absolute` is relative to the first parent whose positioning is not `static`, or the `body` if none are found.  `fixed` is positioned to the window frame.  Your buttons may look like they're in the same place, but the HTML element that triggers the click, is not.

Comment: Thanks gys for trying to help , i found out the issue , OMG i was calling a jquery that causes my problems : 

<script src='js/jquery.listen.min.js'></script>

I jst removed it and evrything worked well 

And wasn't a positioning problem ;)

thanks again .
cheers.